# Is there a way to calculate the size of a pointed vector through sizeof()?

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof

Even if I write this statement

```
char *test= new char[35];
```

sizeof(test) will always return 4 (or another number depending on the system) rather than 35. I assume that this is because the size of a pointer is strictly the physical "pointing entity" and not the amount of memory reserved for that pointer. Is it correct?

Moreover, is there a way to retrieve the amount of memory reserved for a particular pointer using sizeof()?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, and no, there is no way. You have to remember what you allocated. Also (obligatory): use `std::vector` or `std::string`.

Comment: Yes. No. `sizeof` is a compile-time property. The amount of memory allocated is a run-time one. Moreover, in some cases, even the C++ implementation may have no access to that information after the allocation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.

Pointers are just plain variables (generally implemented as integer addresses) — that they can point to other objects is irrelevant to `sizeof`. Don't think about them as something "magic", that is somehow intimately bound to what they point to. Pointers are no more than a street number.

I'm bringing this up because of :

> [...] the size of a pointer is strictly the physical "pointing entity"
>   and not the amount of memory **reserved for that pointer**.

In your line of code :

- An array of 35 `char`s is allocated in dynamic memory
- Its first element's address is returned by `new`
- You keep this address in `test`.

Note that any notion of array, or size thereof, has vanished before the second step. The pointer knows nothing about it. *You* know.

If you want to retrieve the size of the array, you'll need to keep track of it yourself in a separate variable, or use a class that does it for you, namely `std::vector<char>`.

Answer (score 4):

> I assume that this is because the size of a pointer is strictly the physical "pointing entity" and not the amount of memory reserved for that pointer. Is it correct?

Yes, this is correct; you are taking the `sizeof()` a pointer. A pointer is an address in memory; on 32-bit systems this will be 4 bytes. 64-bit systems it will be 8 bytes.

> Moreover, is there a way to retrieve the amount of memory reserved for a particular pointer using sizeof()?

No. `sizeof()` knows nothing about what a pointer points at; it's a compile-time calculation. Getting this size will depend how it's been allocated.

In general you should be using `std::vector<>`. To get the size of a `std::vector<>`, use `std::vector<>::size()`.

Comment: Yes, one can retrieve the amount of memory reserved for a particular pointer using `sizeof`. That's not the amount of memory it points to though, and especially not the fraction of that you really want to access through it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answers, from a normal pointer there is no way to know the amount of memory that has been reserved at the point where it is pointing to, because it is still pointing to garbage.

As soon as you fill the memory with a C-String you can get the length with `strlen(test)` because it looks for the end of string byte (0x0).

A better solution would be to use an array:

```
char test[35];
szie_t size = sizeof(test); //< returns 35
```

Comment: How are you going to pass the size as a template argument if you *don't* know it at compile-time ?

Comment: @Quentin: You are right. The template argument has to be `const`. Thank you. Editing my answer.